# Does storing the username in the session['user'] safe? c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, session

I have the following code in my web application asp.net using C#:

```
            bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(username.Text, password.Text);
            if (isValid == true)
            {
                Session["user"] = username.Text;
            }
```

The `username` is actually a textbox. The end-user will key in their username and password, which will authenticate against a AD (Active Directory) server using the `PrincipalContext pc`.

So, I was wondering if it is safe or are there improvement to be make for the above code so that it can be more secure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, storing the username in the session is safe because the session is stored on the server. On the other hand you probably want to read about [Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) to make sure that you are not reinventing some wheels.